# Why does everything disappear on the screen after 1 second?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

somehow does everything disappear on screen after one second.

My browser just says the following error :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

I have now Idea what the problem is.
i just know there is a problem with the variable "row".

maybe i posted to much of the code. sorry for that

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var FPS = 30;

var map = [ [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
          ]


var ts = 20
var tss = 0
var row = 0
var tr = 0

function drawtiley(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(tss, tr, 20, 20);
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fill();
};
function drawtiler(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(tss, tr, 20, 20);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fill();
};

function drawlvl() {
    for(var o = 0; o < 5; o++ ){
        for(var i = 0 ; i < map.length; i++){
            if(map[row][i] === 0) {
                drawtiley()
            }
            else if (map[row][i] === 1) {
                drawtiler()
            }

            tss = tss + ts;
        };
        tss = 0;
        row = row + 1;
        tr = tr + 20;

    }
    row = 0;
    tr = 0;
}
function draw() {
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    drawlvl();

}

function update() {



}


function tick() {
    draw();

}

setInterval( tick, 1000 / FPS );
```

Comment: I cleaned up this code and removed some of the redundant variables.  http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/tBLZx/1/  Just in case this helps :) (I am really doing absolutely anything to avoid getting real work done :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop has `row` go through the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 before stopping.

But your `map` array only goes up to `map[3]`. `map[4]` doesn't exist, hence an error.

Your `o` variable seems completely pointless. Why not do `for(row=0; row<map.length; row++)`?

Comment: Could the OP have meant for `for(var o = 0; o < 5; o++ ){` to be `for(var row = 0; row < 5; row++ ){`?